# Parallel execution of model prediction in a for loop

Tags: python, keras, parallel-processing

I want to run predictions of a keras model on my input several times in a for loop. Is there a way to parallelize this for loop as each iteration of the loop is independent of the other? I just want to store the predictions of each iteration in the `mc_predictions` array.

```
mc_predictions = []
for i in range(100):
    y_p = model.predict(x)
    mc_predictions.append(y_p)
```

I am using a dropout layer in my model wheer I have set the training attribute to True. Hence, every time I would be getting different results as different neurons would be deactivated in each iteration. I am using monte carlo estimation here.

Comment: why you want to predict on same data multiple times?

Comment: I want the probability score of each iteration and make a statistical analysis on it.

Comment: What makes you think there will be a difference in scores while predicting on same data? Is the model re-trained in each iteration? From the code you posted I can't see the model is re-trained.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. I have edited the question now,

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *"Is there a way to **parallelize this** for loop as each iteration of the loop is independent of the other?"*

Well, without a deeper look inside the actual `model`-instance not.

> <sub>*The `model`-instance could easily be a state-full-system and changing some part of its internal state by each call to the `.predict()`-method ... so one cannot be sure a-priori, without re-inspecting the `model`'s implementation, could one?
> – user3666197 [6 min ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211686/parallel-execution-of-model-prediction-in-a-for-loop#comment110027967_62212249)*</sub>

As the trailer note [was](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62211686/2) added *"...different neurons would be deactivated in each iteration."* the landscape has changed.

There is no way to make the by-definition pure-**`[SERIAL]`** process to "happen" become a True-**`[PARALLEL]`**.

Q.E.D.

---

> <sub>*But **is this really a pure serial process?** I mean, each iteration is independent. What neurons get deactivated in an iteration does not matter as long as random neurons are getting deactivated.
> – [Crazzay1903](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13587380/crazzay1903) [4 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62211686/parallel-execution-of-model-prediction-in-a-for-loop/62212465#comment110028387_62212465)*</sub>

In the **most probable** case **yes**, it is a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** process ( unless somehow & thoroughly proven not to be - but, then it would also fail in a trap of not remaining a repeatable & re-validation ready science ( one may argue it could legally become a principally non-deterministic random process - ***fair, ok*** - yet, even then the proof of having achieved such a robustly non-deterministic random process, so as to be able to proof it does not lose any of its ultimate-randomness-quality property under some True-**`[PARALLEL]`** process implementation ( if there were any such after having been tried & proofed to be such ) but then, the **`.predict()`**-method must, and cannot otherwise, becomes more a clairvoyance, than any rigorous, quantitatively supported fair scientific method, doesn't it? ) which is not a goal, is it? ).

Q.E.D.

Comment: But is this really a pure serial process? I mean, each iteration is independent. What neurons get deactivated in an iteration does not matter as long as random neurons are getting deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the same result at each iteration, I don't get the point of why you would want to do this.

Maybe you're be looking for something like a stratified k-fold approach, where you model trains and validates across different samples of data.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I am using a dropout layer in my model wheer I have set the training attribute to ```True```. Hence, every time I would be getting different results as different neurons would be deactivated in each iteration. I am using monte carlo estimation here.

Comment: **How** comes that you seem to be so sure of your claim *"You would get **the same result** at each iteration"* **to be true?** The `model`-instance could easily be a state-full-system and changing some part of its internal state by each call to the **`.predict()`**-method ... so one cannot be sure a-priori, without re-inspecting the `model`'s implementation, could one?

Comment: Lol, the author has injected the same at the same time :o)

Comment: @user3666197 Exactly what I was trying to imply. But forgot to add that part in the question. My apologies.